# Provide arguments to multiple parameters from a single object without altering the function call?

Tags: r

Is there any way to provide multiple inputs to a function as a single object?

#### Example

Suppose a function expects 2 inputs

```
funct <- function(x, y) {
  x * y
}

funct(2, 7)
# [1] 14
```

Can we provide both inputs as one object somehow?

```
inputs <- c(2, 7)
funct(inputs)
Error in funct(inputs) : argument "y" is missing, with no default

inputs <- list(2, 7)
funct(inputs)
Error in funct(inputs) : argument "y" is missing, with no default
```

I want to achieve this only by changing the input, not by editing the function nor function call (i.e. no using `do.call()`). Is there a way?

That is, the function must not change, the way it is called must not change (i.e. no using `do.call()` or otherwise changing the function)

#### Desired result

I need to change `inputs` to anything, so that

```
funct(inputs)
# [1] 14
```

Comment: @David [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21914971/using-a-single-object-to-pass-multiple-arguments-to-a-function) achieves the same thing but not in the way I need (I need it *only* by changing the input) as I have no control over the function or the way the function is called

Comment: `inputs <- list(2, 7) ; do.call(funct, inputs)` isn't what you want?

Comment: You can perhaps do `funct(c(2, 7)[1], c(2, 7)[2])`.

Comment: I need to really stress that the function and the way it is called cannot change, it will always be `funct(input)`. The only thing I can change is the `input` object (to anything at all)

Comment: I guess a preliminary question would be "is there any way (any way at all) of providing 1 input to a function that expects 2?"

Comment: `do.call(funct, inputs)` is the only way I know of. I'm really feeling this is becoming an XY question.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I have these constraints because I'm working within existing software, so I can only change certain things and others are absolutely static

Comment: To appreciate keenness for solving, it's because if I can find a way, I will avoid introducing backwards incompatibility. Always a nice thing

Answer (score 1):

So from your question, I understand that u need to pass the value of both x,y using a single parameter to the function.

The best way to accomplish this my passing a list or dictionary and using the same inside the function:

if you pass it as a list or array then do this

```
`funct <- function(x) {
  x[[1]] * x[[2]]
}`

`inputs <- list(2, 7)
 funct(inputs)`
```

if you are passing it as a dictionary, you will have the advantage of naming the values:

```
`funct <- function(input) {
  library(hash)
  input[["x"]] * input[["y"]]
}`

`library(hash)
 inputs <- hash() 
 inputs[["x"]] <- 2
 inputs[["y"]] <- 7
 funct(inputs)`
```

Or you can do the following with your existing function:
     `do.call(funct,list(2,7))`

Comment: Hi Vikrant thanks for trying. Both approaches involve changing the function. I cannot change the function nor the way it is called (i.e. `funct(inputs)`) appreciate the suggestions thoug

Comment: I think u didn't read the last line which can work with your existing function.

Comment: Trying the second solution involves changing the function (something I cannot do), but if we try without changing the function we get: `Error in funct(inputs) : argument "y" is missing, with no default`. I think it's pretty cool you can make a hash in R though, I didn't know that. You get my upvote for that alone, even though it doesn't solve the immediate problem

Comment: `do.call(funct,list(2,7))`  works with your existing function. Which I have mentioned in the last line

Comment: I can't use `do.call()` either. I can't change the function, and I can't change the way it's called. Only `inputs` can change

Comment: For the record, I don't think what I'm asking is possible, but I'm asking in case there's some way that I haven't discovered. The first things I tried were a vector and a list, and the hash is an awesome idea. Maybe it's not possible..